# What is the Area in shaded Region?(Tricky one)involves Circles,Rectangle,Triangle

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

[image]

I have solved so far this

Image is in the form of link

Rectangle area$= 10*20=200cm^2$
Circle diameter=$10cm$
Radius=$5cm$
1 circle area=$3.1456*5^=78.64cm^2$
2 circle area=$2*78.64=157.28$
Area outside circle boundry=$200-157.2=42.72cm^2$
Area in the lower triangle=$42.72/2=21.36cm^2$
Area of Square if we draw line in between=$100cm^2$
Area outside of circle in square=$100-78.64=21.36cm^2$
Area of each of size outside of circle halved=$21.36/8=2.67cm^2$

But the triangle line deosn't properly half the area on circle sides in squares what to do?

Estimated could be this=$18.69cm^2$

But this is not true because the line cutting doesn't properly half it.
Answer Plz!

Comment: Oh Nice thanks now what to do with this shall i delete ?

Comment: I don't think there is a downside to leaving it here. It will just get closed as a duplicate (it will still be there, but no one will be able to answer it, will it appear in the unanswered queue).

Comment: @HümayunOkhtar where do you get this question ?

Comment: same homework sheet? ^^

Comment: It was shared on chineese Social network site and they said this is what chineese pupils get in school and outside of China adults can't solve it.